# Slicing an array with a function without using Array.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, slice

In my coding class I have a homework question that I'm stuck on!
I'm using Hackerrank. I think I'm over thinking a lot of things, but I need help, I'm new at this and I'm close to crying! Haha! Sorry about the backticks idk how to format codeblocks sorry! This is Javascript btw!!

The problem:

Write a function called slice, which accepts an array, and two numbers. The function should return a new array with the elements starting at the index of the first number and going until the index of the second number. If the third parameter is greater than the length of the array, it should slice until the end of the array. Do not use the built in Array.slice() function!

The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY.
The function accepts following parameters:

1. INTEGER_ARRAY arr
2. INTEGER index
3. INTEGER len

the function started off as

```
    `function slice(arr, index, len) {

    }`
```

After looking at other forums with similar problems, I tried this, but it isn't working and I think I'm overthinking it.

```
`function slice(arr, index, len) {
let result = [];
from = Math.max(index, 0);
to = Math.min(len);

if((!len) || (len > arr.length)) {
for(let i = from; i<arr.length; i++) {
result.push(arr[i]);}
}  
else { 
for(let i = from; i<to; i++) {
result.push(arr[i]);
}
}
return result;
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

try this once and let me know if it works, tbh I didn't got why you have written (!len).

```
function slice(arr, index, len) {
let result = [];
from = Math.max(index, 0);

if((!len) || ((from+len) > arr.length)) {
for(let i = from; i<arr.length; i++) {
result.push(arr[i]);}
}  
else { 
    for(let i = from; i<from + len; i++) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know what I'm doing. The code didn't work again. :(

Comment: the code starts off this is the only info they give you to start writing   
  
function slice(arr, index, len) {

}